# NSMutableArray Sort Using Selector

Tags: objective-c, sorting

I have googled, searched stackoverflow without satisfying answers.

In the documentation, it states that:

> sortUsingSelector: Sorts the array’s
>   elements in ascending order, as
>   determined by the comparison method
>   specified by a given selector.
>
> - (void)sortUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator
>     Parameters comparator A selector that
>     specifies the comparison method to use
>     to compare elements in the array. The
>     comparator message is sent to each
>     object in the array and has as its
>     single argument another object in the
>     array. The comparator method should
>     return NSOrderedAscending if the array
>     is smaller than the argument,
>     NSOrderedDescending if the array is
>     larger than the argument, and
>     NSOrderedSame if they are equal.

I'm trying to understand how it really works. So if I have this method in my object within
array class:

```
- (NSComparisonResult) compareNames: (id) element
{
    return [userName compare: [element userName]];
}
```

And execute it with

```
[myArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareNames:);
```

It works. The problem is I don't know why it works. The return type for NSComparisonResult
are either Ascending, Same, or Descending. From what I get by reading documentation is
the compareNames method is sent to every object in the myArray and compare the selected
object property (in this case is userName) with the userName in another object within the
same array. (Like the [0] array is compared to the [1] array). I want to know how this
whole process is going.

Update 1: Sorting Algorithm for Multiple Keys

I missed the ! in the comparison. It should be right like this:

```
NSComparisonResult res;
res = [[self userName] compare: [element userName]];
if(res == NSOrderedSame) res = [[self email] compare: [element email]];
return res;
```

As for sorting into descending, you can use switch or if to revert the NSComparisonResult value by replacing "return res" with this:

```
switch (res)
    {
        case NSOrderedAscending:
            return NSOrderedDescending;
            break;
        case NSOrderedDescending :
            return NSOrderedAscending;
            break;
        default:
            return NSOrderedSame;
            break;
    }*/
```

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Basically, it compares all paires of objects and swaps them, if they are in the wrong order. (In reality however, one doesn't have to compare all paires, _n*log(n)_ are sufficient.)

Comment: Does sorting always in Ascending? What if I want to sort by multiple values. Like sorting by name, followed by sorting by email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your subquestions in the comments:

Does sorting always need to be Ascending? - `NSOrderedAscending` & `NSOrderedDescending` are just symbolic here, you might better think of them as "object comes before argument" and "object comes after argument" *in the sort order*. E.g. if you are storing an array of `NSNumber` then "1 compareTo:2" should return `NSOrderedAscending` if you want to sort with increasing value, and `NSOrderedDescending` if you want to sort with decreasing value.

How do you sort with multiple keys? - Any sorting algorithm only needs to know if one item comes before, after, or at the same position as another. *How* you determine that is up to you. To use two sort keys then in pseudo-code the algorithm is:

```
To compare item1 and item2
    order = [item1.key1 compareTo:item2.key1];
    if (order == NSOrderedSame) order = [item1.key2 compareTo:item2.key2];
    return order
```

Extend to more keys or more complex comparisons as needed.

---

Followup to comment:

Sorry, but the supplied algorithm *does* do a 2 key sort, and in general combining the keys *may not and is wasteful*.

In English sorting by two keys goes as follows: first compare the first key of each object, if they compare not equal then return their ordering. If they compare equal then move on and compared the second key of each object and return their ordering.

This is exactly what the pseudo code above does.

Combining multiple keys is problematic for a number of reasons:

1. You must combine them using a separator which cannot occur in the keys. As a simple example consider sorting by given name, family name when you have the two people "jack yolander" and "jacky olander" - a naive joining produces "jackyolander" for both and they would sort equal. So you need a separator which *cannot* occur in any of the keys.
2. If the keys are of different types, e.g. a string and a number, you end up converting them all to strings to combine - *wasteful* and maybe even inaccurate.
3. Simply combining them is *wasteful* - you are generating objects you don't need.

Etc. Just compare the keys in pairs until you either find two which differ or get to the last pair. Works for any number of keys, of any types, and isn't wasteful.

Comment: The algorithm you provided only sort one single key. Because once you sort out all the key1, the sorting will resort all the sorted array using key2. I have tried it and it doesn't give the result I want. I'm not sure how the sorting process is taking within the classes. But I can attain the result I want by combining both key into single NSString and sort them using only one compare method. I have included the code above.

Comment: Sorry, but the supplied algorithm does do a 2 key sort, and in general combining the keys may not and is wasteful.

Comment: I missed the and typed ! during the comparison. No wonder it doesn't yield out the result I expect. Yours is working perfectly. I'm sorry that I didn't check my code correctly before editing or replying. And thanks for your detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

`sortUsingSelector` will be using Quicksort or a similar sorting algorithm to sort the array. Sorting algorithms need to be able to compare two items in the collection to be sorted and determine where they should appear relative to each other in sorted order. Should A appear before B, after B or immediately alongside it? Your custom sort method (`compareNames` in your example) is all the sorting algorithm needs to determine that ordering.

Have a look at the [Wikipedia entry for sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) for some background on this.

You won't find much online about this if you search for e.g. "sortUsingSelector". This isn't an Objective-C-specific issue, pretty much all programming languages have sort routines that use a user-defined comparison function to do the sorting.